# Access Google Container builder logs with a service account - 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-container-builder

I have a service account that triggers builds on Google Container Builder. This works fine but now I would like to retrieve build logs using that service account.

Here is the code that fetches the log (the token is obtained using [google-auto-auth](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/google-auto-auth) package and this part works well in other places, so I really don't think this is the issue):

```
var url = logsBucket + '/log-' + buildId + '.txt';
debug('Requesting log at %s', url);
request
  .get(url)
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    var log = res.body;
    debug('Received build log : %o', log);
    cb(null, log);
  });
```

Currently, this fails with 401 Unauthorized although the service account has access to the following roles:

- Admin kubernetes engine
- Admin storage
- Admin objects in storage
- Cloud container builder
- Reader Cloud container builder
- Reader storage objects

This is the error:

```
{
  "message": "Forbidden",
  "stack": "Error: Forbidden\n    at Request.callback (/app/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:696:15)\n [...]",
  "status": 403,
  "response": {
    "req": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/{PROJECT_ID}.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/log-42602b35-af02-4e75-8100-8a3bd0e720fb.txt",
      "headers": {
        "user-agent": "node-superagent/3.8.2",
        "authorization": "Bearer {BEARER_TOKEN}"
      }
    },
    "header": {
      "x-guploader-uploadid": "{SOME-UPLOAD-ID}",
      "content-type": "application/xml; charset=UTF-8",
      "content-length": "337",
      "date": "Wed, 10 Jan 2018 11:06:54 GMT",
      "expires": "Wed, 10 Jan 2018 11:06:54 GMT",
      "cache-control": "private, max-age=0",
      "server": "UploadServer",
      "alt-svc": "...",
      "connection": "close"
    },
    "status": 403
  }
}
```

Any idea why the request fails with 403 ? Could it come from a missing scope ? I only set `scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'` so far.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I'll try your answer tommorow, keep you posted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### GCS permissions predate IAM and thus work a little differently.

To view the build logs, the Service Account in question needs to be a **Viewer** on the project in addition to have the **Builder Editor** role.

- `role/viewer` includes role `role/cloudbuild.builds.viewer`
- `role/cloudbuild.builds.editor`

As a last step you may want to: (Not necessary)

- **Disable** the Container Builder API and re-enable it. Doing so should give your service account access to your project again.

Please also look at: [**docs**](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-control)

Comment: The missing roles did the job, no need to restart the API. Thanks a lot